# Perl precompiled regex - utf8

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, utf-8

When I do:

```
use strict; use warnings;
my $regex = qr/[[:upper:]]/;
my $line = MyModule::get_my_line_from_external_source(); #file, db, etc...
print "upper here\n" if( $line =~ $regex );
```

How perl will know when it must match only `ascii uppercase` and when `utf8 uppercase`?
It is an precompiled regex - so somewhat perl must know, what is uppercase. Dependent on locale settings? If yes, how to match utf8 uppercase in "C" locale with precompiled regex?

updated based on tchrist's comments:

```
use strict; use warnings; use Encode;
my $regex = qr/[[:upper:]]/;

my $line = XXX::line();
print "$line: upper1 ", ($line =~ $regex) ? "YES" : "NO", "\n";

my $uline = Encode::decode_utf8($line);
print "$uline: upper2 ", ($uline =~ $regex) ? "YES" : "NO", "\n";

package XXX;
sub line { return "alpha-Ω"; } #returning octets - not utf8 chars
```

The output is:

```
alpha-Ω: upper1 NO
alpha-Ω: upper2 YES
```

What does it mean, that the precompiled regex is not 'hard-precompiled' but 'soft-precompiled' - so perl replace '[[:upper:]]' based on the utf8 flag of the matched $line.

Comment: If you use literal UTF-8 in your source code, then all you need is a `use utf8` in scope. Perl will decode it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before Perl 5.14, this was not very well defined.

With 5.14, the pattern known how it was compiled, and you have the `/u`, `/l`, `/d`, `/a`, or `/aa` pattern modifiers. You can also say

```
use re "/u";
```

or

```
use re "/msu";
```

to turn all those flags on in the lexical scope.

For example, under 5.14:

```
% perl -le 'print qr/foo/'
(?^:foo)
% perl -E 'say qr/foo/'
(?^u:foo)
% perl -E 'say qr/foo/l'
(?^l:foo)
```

I would stear clear of locales; just use all-Unicode.

BTW, I would make darned sure that that "external source" gave you back a string that was properly decoded; that is, has its UTF8 flag turned on.  Character functions work poorly on encoded strings, because they really want decoded strings instead.

Comment: So, in perl < 5.14 what is the correct way matching utf8 [:upper:]? Something like: "my $regsrc = Encode::decode_utf8('[[:upper:]]'); my $regex = qr/$regsrc/; # or how? Or enough put "use utf8;" at the start?

Comment: `use utf8` isn’t enough to get Unicode strings semantics for your own source code on U+80–U+FF. You should be able to say `utf::upgrade($string)`. That assumes the string has already been decoded, or else is a correct encoding of UTF-8 and if so marks it as decoded. Then any regex should work right on it. You can use `utf8::is_utf8($string)` to test for whether its UTF8 flag is already on. The Unicode property `\p{upper}` will assume Unicode semantics, but again this requires that byte strings have already been converted into character strings. I wouldn’t ever use `[[:upper:]]`, personally.

Comment: Prefer [Unicode::Semantics](http://p3rl.org/Unicode::Semantics) over just the naked `upgrade` API call. No `is_utf8` test necessary.

Comment: That module is an old workaround to the U+80–U+FF issue, one no longer needed with the `unicode_strings` feature of 5.12 and above. I am not a fan of pulling in dependencies on external CPAN modules when you can get the same thing completely using builtins.